# The parameter 'pageController' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I have copied this code from github but I get errors:

```
BubbleIndicatorPainter(
  {this.dxTarget = 125.0,
    this.dxEntry = 25.0,
    this.radius = 21.0,
    this.dy = 25.0,
    this.pageController})
  : super(repaint: pageController) {
painter = Paint()
  ..color = CustomTheme.white
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;}
```

In particular, BubbleIndicatorPainter gets:

> Non-nullable instance field 'painter' must be initialized.

and pageController gets:

> The parameter 'pageController' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.

I think they are related but I don't know how to solve, and adding required to this.pageController didn't solve the problem.
Thanks for the answers

Comment: Can you add the code of the entire class?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of your code - are you passing BubbleIndicatorPainter() a valid PageController() object?

It looks like your source is [from here](https://github.com/DoanVu0892/doanvu.flutter/blob/744e7427328896b14482dd35520c63dbebbcad2b/flutter_app/lib/customs/bubble.dart)?

If you're compiling with null-safety a variable that can be null will have a declaration with a "?" suffix.  From the link above, pageController is defined as non-nullable.

```
 final PageController pageController;
```

If it could be null the declaration would be:

```
final PageController? pageController;
```

Looking at build() in the linked source, pageController.position is accessed without a null check, so you can't have a null pageController.

The 'default' in the error is a default value in the declaration, which is 'implicitly' null if not provided. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    Color color;
    MyClass({this.color = Colors.white});
}
```

The "implicit default" of "color" is "Colors.white" - the value that gets assigned if you don't provide one to MyClass(), i.e.:

```
MyClass myclass = MyClass(color: Colors.blue); //myclass.color will be Colors.blue
MyClass myclass = MyClass() // myclass.color will be Colors.white
```

If instead MyClass was:

```
class MyClass {
    Color? color;
    MyClass({this.color});
}
```

The implicit default value of color would be 'null' because no default is provided (which is allowed because it's declared with a "?" suffix). I.e.:

```
MyClass myclass = MyClass(color: Colors.blue); //myclass.color will be Colors.blue
MyClass myclass = MyClass() // myclass.color will be null
```

Looking at BubbleIndicatorPainter() it doesn't provide a default value for        this.pageController, which means the implicit default is 'null' (which isn't allowed because it doesn't have a "?" after the type.)

Comment: It wasn't this specific repository but this class is the same. I tried doing the things you listed but the error just changed. I solved by copying the initialization of the painter and pasting it outside the constructor. I have no idea why it worked but it did